# OCI DevOps Deployment Result Notification

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a DevOps project with a deployment pipeline. I want to recive a notification of the deployment result once it fails or succeeds, but I can't find it.
I checked in Rules, and you can set up a notification when the deployment **starts** but not when it finishes.
There is [Deployment Failures Metric](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/devops/using/devops_metrics.htm#:%7E:text=DeploymentFailure-,Deployment%20Failures,-1%20or%200) which could be used as an Alarm. However, 1. my DevOps Metrics aren't working, they're always empty. So, the DevOps namespace isn't showing in the Alarms definition page. 2. it won't be instant.

Is there a way to configure it nativly in OCI, or do I need to depened on 3rd party services/integrations?